# Correlation in excel for range of values

Tags: python, excel, excel-formula, correlation

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o3y1V.png)I have two columns x and y. I want to observe how the correlation changes when x is in 0-10,10-20,20-30 and so on

Comment: and what have you tried till now ? please post your code

Comment: I have used this formula for different values of x
=CORREL(IF(raw_data!F:F<=10,raw_data!F:F,""),raw_data!G:G)
but I have to manually change the range every time

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can sort the column first, and then use the correlation formula.

[image]